# Почему "тяжелый"пишется через ё?

Tags: орфография

Почему "тяжёлый" пишется через "ё"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из Шанского: ТЯЖЁЛЫЙ - искон., суф. производное от тяга, тяжесть, суф. ЁЛ (сравнить: весёлый).

Соответственно,  в слове "тяжелый" следует выделить корень ТЯЖЁЛ, а ЁЛ считать историческим суффиксом. Тогда при наличии исторического чередовании Е/Ё **в корне**  ударный гласный обозначается буквой Ё.

Примечание

Черных также считает ЁЛ в слове "веселый" **очень редким суффиксом** и выделяет корень ВЕС. Существует несколько версий для значения корня (радоваться, наслаждаться), в частности, некоторые лингвисты предполагают что весна и весёлый - это однокоренные слова.

Answer (score 2):

### Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Спорным можно считать вопрос, является ли ё в слове тяжёлый частью корня или суффикса. В полном академическом справочнике «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» (М., 2007) тяжёлый отнесено к перечню корней с сочетанием жё. Написание ё в этом случае обусловлено правилом: пишется ё после шипящих в словах, в корне которых под ударением произносится о, чередующееся с е в других формах или в других словах того же корня: тяжёлый – тяжелее, тяжелеть.

Впрочем, даже если считать ё частью суффикса, отсюда не следует написание слова тяжёлый через о. Д. Э. Розенталь в «Справочнике по правописанию и литературной правке» так формулирует правило о написании о, ё в суффиксах прилагательных после шипящих: «После шипящих под ударением пишется о в соответствии с произношением в суффиксах имён прилагательных: -ов- (ежовый, чесучовый), -он (смешон)». Как мы видим, суффикс -ёл- в этот список не входит.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж и slava1947!

Answer (score 2):

> Почему "тяжелый"пишется через ё?

Почему? Так сложилось. Здесь ***ё*** -- часть уникального суффикса ***ёл.***

См. Бешенкова Е.В., Иванова О.Е., Чельцова Л.К. ***"Объяснительный русский орфографический словарь-справочник"***, М., 2015:

> ***тяжёлый...*** ***ё*** в уникальном суффиксе ***ёл.***
>
> Часто в этом слове выделяют корень ***тяжёл-***, однако сравнение со
>   словами *тяжесть, тяготы* показывает, что в данном случае корень
>   ***тяж/тяг/тя.***

======================================

> В полном академическом справочнике «Правила русской орфографии и
>   пунктуации» (М., 2007) тяжёлый отнесено к перечню корней с сочетанием
>   жё.

Ольга Евгеньевна Иванова и Людмила Константиновна Чельцова, являвшиеся одними из авторов полного академического справочника «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации», за прошедшие со времени выпуска этого справочника годы, похоже, изменили своё мнение по слову ***тяжёлый***. См. выше.

Comment: Слава, а вы не знаете, «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» не переиздавались больше?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду ПАС (полный академический справочник)? Да он, по-моему, каждый год переиздаётся -- без изменений и дополнений. Что же до написания "ё" в слове "тяжёлый", то чем бы это "ёл/ел" ни считать, но при наличии в сравнительной степени буквы "е" (а раньше ведь в языке существовала и форма сравнительной степени  "тяжеле" **с ударением** на первом "е"), логичнее, конечно, и в полном прилагательном сохранять эту букву... Или, лучше сказать, родственную "е" букву -- "ё".

Comment: Да, Слава,вы правы.